# LAMP vs. MEAN vs. Other web application server

Tags: web-applications, webserver, open-source, mean-stack

Can someone note the pros and cons for creating web application with those technologies?

I know that they are not fully comparable (LAMP refers to OS and MEAN not) so in your comparison can you complete the missing criteria (i.e. MEAN recommended OS is ...)

Comment: If you downvoted can you at least tell me why? I want to create a web app with new tech. didn't found a good comparison. I think Im not the only one that need this kind of comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on your needs.

For a small scale project it is fine to stick with the "mean" stack since it is rather platform independant, and "easy" to get started with.
I am assuming you plan on using javascript for your backend?

LAMP is something different.

- L: Linux, but WAMP would be the same for windows (osx has MAMP)
- A: Apache, this is popular, but some people prefer nginx (those are the main web servers out there i think... you can also deploy nodejs projects on those. The main advantage is that they are made for scalability on very large scales if necessary.
- M: Usually stands for MYSQL (but it could equally be MongoDB if you want to use that... or any other DB engine really, such as Postgres or Oracle or even sqLite...
- P: this stands for PHP... It's in my opinion the scripting language of the web. I don't really like it but that's my opinion. As i mentioned earlier you could also deploy javascript (nodeJs) or Python or ruby web projects...

Thus the eventual choice depends entirely on your needs. Do you just want to serve static html pages... use apache or nginx... no need for databases and so on.

If you want to create web applications, first think what you prefer to use... javascript in the backend? Python (with some web framework like django or flask) or ruby (Ruby on rails or sinatra) Or go with something crazy... there are dozens of options of languages.